# JavaScript/Angular1 - Refacto algo/logic condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have 2 conditions that compare 2 models if they exist or not to display different messages.
The object `this.realEstateProjectCurrentProduct` remains the same, it is the properties `housingTax` or `propertyTax` that differs, the case of else remains the same.

```
if (this.realEstateProjectCurrentProduct.housingTax) {
  return this.housingTax = `${this.realEstateProjectCurrentProduct.housingTax} ${this.$translate.instant('currencySymbols.euro')}`
} else {
  return this.housingTax = 'No data'
}
if (this.realEstateProjectCurrentProduct.propertyTax) {
  return this.propertyTax = `${this.realEstateProjectCurrentProduct.propertyTax} ${this.$translate.instant('currencySymbols.euro')}`
} else {
  return this.propertyTax = 'No data'
}
```

How can I improve these 2 conditions since there is too much resemblance between them with Lodash or ecmaScript 2015 for example

Comment: The code above will never get to second if statement, because of all of the return statements you have before assignments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use property destructuring, eg:

```
let { housingTax, propertyTax } = this.realEstateProjectCurrentProduct;
housingTax = housingTax ? `${housingTax} ${this.$translate.instant('currencySymbols.euro')}`: 'no data'
propertyTax = propertyTax ?  `${propertyTax} ${this.$translate.instant('currencySymbols.euro')}` : 'no data'
```

Answer (score 1):

While not the safest approach (magic strings are generally bad) you could try extracting the actual functionality and passing in the name of the property you want to change.

```
function processTax(taxType) {
  if (this.realEstateProjectCurrentProduct[taxType]) {
    this[taxType]= `${this.realEstateProjectCurrentProduct[taxType]} ${this.$translate.instant('currencySymbols.euro')}`
  } else {
    this[taxType]= 'No data'
  }
}

processTax('housingTax');
processTax('propertyTax');
```

If you expect to have more in the future, consider an array:

```
['housingTax', 'propertyTax'].forEach(tax => processTax(tax));
```